# Where can I get siamltex document class from in Debian Linux?

Tags: document-classes, linux

I just got a latex document with siamltex document class from my collaborator. Is this document class packaged in Debian Linux?

Comment: The [Debian package contents search page](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=squeeze&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=siamltex) indicates it's not available in the official repositories. But there shouldn't be any problem with getting the .zip file from [their author info page](http://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php) and extracting it into a folder in your home directory where you'll write your document, or else extracting it into your personal texmf tree.

Comment: @MikeRenfro, thanks for your answer. If you paste it as a proper answer I will accept it. Could you also paste where is my personal texmf tree id Debian (for completeness)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Debian package contents search page](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=squeeze&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=siamltex) indicates it's not available in the official repositories. But there shouldn't be any problem with getting the .zip file from [their author info page](http://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php) and extracting it into a folder in your home directory where you'll write your document, or else extracting it into your personal texmf tree. That is, extracting siamltex.cls, siamltex.sty, and related files into the folder $HOME/texmf/tex/latex/siamltex:

```
me@host:~/texmf/tex/latex/siamltex$ ls -al
total 472
drwx------ 2 me users   4096 2011-10-14 08:03 .
drwx------ 3 me users     40 2011-10-14 08:03 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me users  25249 2011-02-04 14:44 docultex.tex
-rw------- 1 me users   2551 2011-10-14 08:03 lexample.aux
-rw------- 1 me users   6806 2011-10-14 08:03 lexample.log
-rw------- 1 me users 315114 2011-10-14 08:03 lexample.pdf
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me users  26938 2011-02-04 14:46 lexample.tex
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me users   7064 2011-02-04 14:48 siam10.clo
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me users  19617 2007-11-30 15:50 siam.bst
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me users  27434 2011-02-04 14:48 siamltex704.cls
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me users  27412 2011-02-04 14:49 siamltex.cls
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me users   2071 2011-02-04 14:50 siamltex.sty
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me users   2438 2007-11-30 15:50 subeqn.clo
me@host:~/texmf/tex/latex/siamltex$ cd $HOME/Inbox
me@host:~/Inbox$ grep documentclass lexample.tex
\documentclass[final]{siamltex}
me@host:~/Inbox$ pdflatex lexample.tex
...
...
c/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb>
Output written on lexample.pdf (8 pages, 314562 bytes).
Transcript written on lexample.log.
```